# I asked a question on MSE, it was kinda long, but my own construct. I had written everything I knew, but people are discouraging me.

Tags: support, specific-question

As I said in the title itself, I asked a question but it is being downvoted. I followed every guideline but still. If I am wrong then correct me? Why discourage. I am using the word discourage because my brother also uses my account to post a question, and he is kinda sensitive, so I urge you to please tell me what should **I** do? 
They are even voting for closing it. I have got 2 votes till now. 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1440726/can-something-be-done-to-take-this-forward-power-series-calculus-wolfram-ga?noredirect=1#comment2934780_1440726

Answer (score 10):

To me the question seems pretty unclear and unmotivated. You perform some power-series manipulations and  then you ask if this could be useful. This does not seem like a good question for this site to me.

What you should do is give some motivation for the manipulations and sharpen the question by asking something specific.

Or, redact the question.

Answer (score 8):

Why discourage? Because this is not a good post.

It does not ask a clear, focussed question. It provides no motivation, aim or background. It employs seemingly random tangents already in the title, not to mention the body.

Also, I couldn't care less for the mental state of those posting the questions. The question posted is the only thing we *can* judge, and its own merits rather than its poster's should determine its reception. This is not a social networking site, after all.

Let me add that meta threads like this one are usually poorly received. I guess that "The community dares to disagree with me?! :( :S I really really tried :(" is not a popular way of asking what can be done to improve the question at hand.